# How to combine appsink and filesink using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer, pipeline

I'm new to GStreamer and I'm trying to create a pipeline to display a video and record it at the same time. I've managed to make the display part using:

```
ss << "filesrc location=/home/videos/video1.avi ! avidemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! mpeg4videoparse ! avdec_mpeg4 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! appsink name=mysink";
```

Also, I've read that `filesink location=somepath` is used for saving data into a file but I don't know how combine it with the rest of the pipeline.

So, how do I use `appsink` and `filesink` in the same pipeline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GStreamer offers a `tee` element for such cases. Note however that in most cases you will want a `queue` after each branch of a tee to prevent deadlocks. E.g.

```
filesrc location=/home/videos/video1.avi ! avidemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! mpeg4videoparse ! avdec_mpeg4 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! tee name=mytee ! queue ! appsink name=mysink mytee. ! queue ! filesink location=out.raw
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but using `location=out.mp4` instead. Now, when I try to play the output video or when I inspect it with `gst-discover-1.0`, it gives me the next error: _"Could not determine type of stream"_. Any idea of why it could be? Thank you.

Comment: You cannot just rename a file and hope things fix itself. It you want to store raw video into a container you need a muxer for the desired format. Note that in GStreamer the mp4 muxer does not support raw video. The matroska muxer may be an alternative.

Comment: I just tried it with `matroskamux` and works perfectly. The final pipeline is:
`ss << "filesrc location=/home/videos/video1.avi ! avidemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! mpeg4videoparse ! avdec_mpeg4 ! nvvidconv ! video/x-raw,format=I420 ! tee name=mytee ! queue ! appsink name=mysink mytee. ! queue ! matroskamux ! filesink location=/home/videos/out1.mkv";`
Thank you very much for your help.